# key-value syntax in package options

Tags: package-writing, package-options, key-value

I want to create a style file capturing my layout for theorem environments. In particular, I would like to pass an option to the package specifying the level of the theorem counter. So here is a minimal working example:

The style file:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{mytheorem}

\RequirePackage{amsthm}
\newcommand{\level}{}

\DeclareOption{section}{\renewcommand{\level}{section}}
\DeclareOption{chapter}{\renewcommand{\level}{chapter}}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[\level]
\newtheorem{corollary}[\level]{Corollary}
```

The document:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[section]{mytheorem}
\begin{document}
    \begin{corollary}
        Inhalt...
    \end{corollary}
\end{document}
```

However it would be nice to specify the option via a key-value syntax like so:

```
\usepackage[theoremlevel=section]{mytheorem}
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With `xkeyval` it is very simple to provide key values to packages, using `\DeclareOptionX` and `\ProcessOptionsX`, parsing the keys and doing the relevant options/redefinitions.

In order to preset some default values, use `\ExecuteOptionsX{theoremlevel=section}`, for example.

`\DeclareOptionsX*` is meant for processing unknown options.

Package file:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{mytheorem}

\RequirePackage{amsthm}
\RequirePackage{xkeyval}

\newcommand{\level}{}

\DeclareOptionX{theoremlevel}{\renewcommand{\level}{#1}}
\DeclareOptionX*{\PackageWarning{mytheorem}{`\CurrentOption' ignored}}% For unknown options
\ExecuteOptionsX{theoremlevel=section}% Preset keys, 'section' being the default here

\ProcessOptionsX\relax

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[\level]
\newtheorem{corollary}[\level]{Corollary}

\endinput
```

Driver file:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[theoremlevel=chapter,foo]{mytheorem}% foo should provide a warning!
\begin{document}
    \begin{corollary}
        Inhalt...
    \end{corollary}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Of course, there other ways, with `pgfkeys`, `keyval`, `kvoptions`, `l3keys2e` etc.

Answer (score 11):

## A few examples for different packages

All of the following package examples work with the following document when saved as `mytheorem.sty`.

```
\documentclass[]{report}

\usepackage[level=chapter, foo, bar=baz]{mytheorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{corollary}
  Inhalt
\end{corollary}
\end{document}
```

### `expkv` family

<sup>Disclaimer: I'm the package author.</sup>

In the `expkv` family the package `expkv-opt` allows to parse package and class options with `expkv` sets. The main macros you can use for this are `\ekvoProcessGlobalOptions` (which will parse the options provided to `\documentclass`) and `\ekvoProcessLocalOptions` (which will parse the options directly provided to the current class/package).

You can conveniently define common key types using `expkv-def`. It provides the macro `\ekvdefinekeys` that will parse a key=value list to define new keys (a similar approach is also taken by other packages like `l3keys`, `pgfkeys`, or `options`).

**The package file**

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{mytheorem}

\RequirePackage{amsthm}
\RequirePackage{expkv-opt,expkv-def}

\ekvdefinekeys{mytheorem}
  {
     store   level = \mytheorem@level
    ,initial level = section
    % specify what happens for unknown keys
    ,unknown code  =
      \PackageWarning{mytheorem}
        {Unknown option `\detokenize{#1}' received `\detokenize{#2}'}
    ,unknown noval =
      \PackageWarning{mytheorem}{Unknown option `\detokenize{#1}'}
  }

% process options given to \documentclass
\ekvoProcessGlobalOptions{mytheorem}
% for the next ekvoProcess... use the unknown handlers like defined for the set
\ekvoUseUnknownHandlers*
% process options given to this package
\ekvoProcessLocalOptions{mytheorem}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[\mytheorem@level]
\newtheorem{corollary}[\mytheorem@level]{Corollary}
```

### LaTeX-kernel

This requires no packages at all. Recent kernels have this functionality built in. The only two solutions in this list that support LaTeX's new mechanism for options passed to a package when it was loaded beyond the first time (as of writing this) are this one and `expkv-opt` (with `\ekvoProcessFutureOptions`). Under the hood the key=value system used is the same as `l3keys` (see the next example).

**The package file**

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesExplPackage{mytheorem}{}{}{}

\RequirePackage{amsthm}

\DeclareKeys
  {
     level   .tl_set:N         = \l__mytheorem_level_tl
    ,level   .initial:n        = section
    ,level   .value_required:n = true
    ,unknown .code:n           =
      \PackageWarning{mytheorem}{Unknown~ option~ `\l_keys_key_str'}
  }

\ProcessKeyOptions

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[\l__mytheorem_level_tl]
\newtheorem{corollary}[\l__mytheorem_level_tl]{Corollary}
```

Or if you prefer, using only LaTeX2e syntax (almost only, afaik, there is currently no 2e-name for `.value_required:n`):

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{mytheorem}

\RequirePackage{amsthm}

\DeclareKeys
  {
     level   .store            = \mytheorem@level
    ,level   .value_required:n = true
  }
\SetKeys{level=section}
\DeclareUnknownKeyHandler{\PackageWarning{mytheorem}{Unknown~ option~ `#1'}}

\ProcessKeyOptions

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[\mytheorem@level]
\newtheorem{corollary}[\mytheorem@level]{Corollary}
```

### `l3keys`

The `l3keys` package provides a very stable and well thought out key=value solution. It is using the `expl3` programming conventions. Support for package and class options in recent versions of LaTeX is available out of the box with `\ProcessKeyOptions` (see the section LaTeX-kernel above), for older LaTeX versions the functionality is added by the `l3keys2e` package which provides the macro `\ProcessKeysOptions`.

Keys are defined using `\keys_define:nn` with a key=value interface.

**The package file**

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesExplPackage{mytheorem}{}{}{}

\RequirePackage{amsthm}
\RequirePackage{l3keys2e}

\keys_define:nn { mytheorem }
  {
     level   .tl_set:N         = \l__mytheorem_level_tl
    ,level   .initial:n        = section
    ,level   .value_required:n = true
    ,unknown .code:n           =
      \PackageWarning{mytheorem}{Unknown~ option~ `\l_keys_key_str'}
  }

\ProcessKeysOptions { mytheorem }

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[\l__mytheorem_level_tl]
\newtheorem{corollary}[\l__mytheorem_level_tl]{Corollary}
```

### `pgfkeys`

Is part of `pgf` & Ti*k*Z. It is probably one of the most used key=value solutions and had a major influence on packages like `l3keys` and `options`. Support for class and packages options is added by the `pgfopts` package via the macro `\ProcessPgfOptions`. Keys are defined using `\pgfkeys` or `\pgfqkeys` with a key=value interface.

**The package file**

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{mytheorem}

\RequirePackage{amsthm}
\RequirePackage{pgfopts}

\pgfqkeys{/mytheorem}
  {
    .is family
    ,level/.store in = \mytheorem@level
    ,level/.initial  = section
    ,.unknown/.code  =
      \PackageWarning{mytheorem}{Unknown option `\pgfkeyscurrentname'}
  }

\ProcessPgfOptions{/mytheorem}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[\mytheorem@level]
\newtheorem{corollary}[\mytheorem@level]{Corollary}
```

### `options`

`options` is a seldom used package heavily inspired by `pgfkeys`. It comes with support for package options out of the box. Defining new keys looks pretty similar to `pgfkeys`.

**The package file**

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{mytheorem}

\RequirePackage{amsthm}
\RequirePackage{options}

\newcommand*\mytheorem@level{section}

\options
  {
    /mytheorem/.new family, /mytheorem/.cd
    ,level/.is def = \mytheorem@level
    ,@unknown/.new cmd 2 = \PackageWarning{mytheorem}{Unknown option `#1'}
  }

\options@ProcessOptions{/mytheorem}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[\mytheorem@level]
\newtheorem{corollary}[\mytheorem@level]{Corollary}
```