# Style file with option to change pagesizes

Tags: typography

I would like to have a latex style file `nutsi.sty` that includes the `my-definition` feature.  I also want to set the pagesize (21cm x 21cm) and sets the entire document in bold typeface.

Managed to make a latex file that uses nutsi.sty

```latex
    \documentclass{book}
    \usepackage{nutsi}
    
    \end{document}


Although this style file sets a page-size of 21cm x 21cm, how can I
introduce an option that lets the user select either 1) a 21cm x 21cm
pagesize; 2) an A4 pagesize; or a B5 pagesize.   

This is the file `nutsi.sty`.

    \usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{ paperheight=21cm, paperwidth=21cm, left=8mm, right=8mm,
      top=21mm, bottom=21mm}
    
    \usepackage{fix-cm}
    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand\normalsize{%
       \@setfontsize\normalsize{13pt}{15pt}
       \abovedisplayskip 10\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus5\p@
       \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus3\p@
       \belowdisplayshortskip 6\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus3\p@
       \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
       \let\@listi\@listI}
    \makeatother
    
    \usepackage{bm}                % makes bold arguments
    \usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}  % loads 317 named rgb colours
    
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amsthm}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    
    % use boldface for whole document
    \boldmath
    \renewcommand{\seriesdefault}{\bfdefault}
    
    \newtheoremstyle{my-definition} % name of style
    {8pt}       % measure of space above definition, e.g. {3pt}
    {8pt}       % measure of space below definition, e.g. {3pt}
    {\itshape}  % name of font for body of example
    {}          % measure of space to indent, e.g. {3pt}
    {\bfseries\itshape}           % name of font for heading
    {\textcolor{DarkOrange3}{.}}  % punctuation between heading and body
    { }         % space after theorem heading
    {\thmname{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}
     \textcolor{DarkOrange3}{\textbf{\thmnumber{#2}}}
     \thmnote{\textit{({#3})}} }
    
    \theoremstyle{my-definition}
    \newtheorem{definition}{\textcolor{Blue3}{Definition}}[section]
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if you show us your version of `nutsi.sty` so we don't have to guess what might, or might not, be in it.

Comment: For the point "entire document in bold typeface" see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/511967/117050

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following uses `expkv-opt` to provide package options with a key=value interface.

With this you have one option `paper` that takes one of the three possible values `21`, `a4`, and `b5`.

Please note that in a package you should use `\RequirePackage` instead of `\usepackage`, and you don't need `\makeatletter`.

### `nutsi.sty`

```
\ProvidesPackage{nutsi}[2022-04-25 custom style by Ephram]

\RequirePackage{expkv-opt,expkv-def}
\ekvdefinekeys{nutsi}
  {
    choice-enum paper = \nutsi@paper {21, a4, b5}
  }
\ekvoProcessLocalOptions{nutsi}

\RequirePackage{geometry}
\ifcase\nutsi@paper
  \geometry{paperheight=21cm, paperwidth=21cm}
\or
  \geometry{a4paper}
\or
  \geometry{b5paper}
\fi

\geometry{left=8mm, right=8mm, top=21mm, bottom=21mm}

\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\renewcommand\normalsize{%
   \@setfontsize\normalsize{13pt}{15pt}
   \abovedisplayskip 10\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus5\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus3\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 6\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus3\p@
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
   \let\@listi\@listI}

\RequirePackage{bm}                % makes bold arguments
\RequirePackage[x11names]{xcolor}  % loads 317 named rgb colours

\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{amsthm}
\RequirePackage{amssymb}

% use boldface for whole document
\boldmath
\renewcommand{\seriesdefault}{\bfdefault}

\newtheoremstyle{my-definition} % name of style
{8pt}       % measure of space above definition, e.g. {3pt}
{8pt}       % measure of space below definition, e.g. {3pt}
{\itshape}  % name of font for body of example
{}          % measure of space to indent, e.g. {3pt}
{\bfseries\itshape}           % name of font for heading
{\textcolor{DarkOrange3}{.}}  % punctuation between heading and body
{ }         % space after theorem heading
{\thmname{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}
 \textcolor{DarkOrange3}{\textbf{\thmnumber{#2}}}
 \thmnote{\textit{({#3})}} }

\theoremstyle{my-definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{\textcolor{Blue3}{Definition}}[section]
```

### the document

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[paper=b5]{nutsi}

\usepackage{duckuments}

\begin{document}
\duckument
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is `expkv-opt`, a latex built-in feature?

Comment: I am actually getting `! LaTeX Error: File expkv-opt.sty' not found.`.

Comment: @Ephram after your previous question about locating the file `.sty`, does this answer your question? If not, add more comments asking for clarifications and I am sure Skillmon will help but if it does with your recent answer, make sure to tick it as done so the `community bot` doesn't bump it to the top! All the best

Comment: Yes it answers the question, although using `expkv-opt` is giving me `Undefined control sequence` on `\IfFormatAtLeastTF`.

Comment: @Ephram I have never seen that error before but I am sure that Skillmon has and will be able to help, sorry! Check back in tomorrow and there will probably be an edit or an answer here.

Comment: @Ephram `expkv-opt` doesn't support too-old kernel versions. Update your LaTeX-installation if you want to use it. But there are alternatives providing similar functionality, see for example there: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/615014/117050

Comment: @Ephram another alternative would be to use LaTeX2e's original built in option processing (which is less flexible, but for 3 alternatives should easily suffice, `\DeclareOption` and `\ProcessOptions` are the macros you want, just search for those).